# NSManagedObject in Swift lacking CoreDataGeneratedAccessors

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject, accessor

Did auto-generated accessor methods for `NSSets` in `Core Data` entities disappear in Swift? Or could this be an `Xcode`'s bug? I don't find the answer to this issue...

Thanks in advance

Comment: The accessor methods are generated in Swift as well. can you please provide details on the steps to generate the methods>

Comment: @rshankar I can't access them...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I see in Xcode 7 beta 5 the auto generated accessors aren't there anymore if you generate to `swift` but `Objective-C` adds them?